# How to implement a method of a generic class?

Tags: typescript

[TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-classes) give the style for creating a generic class with generic methods as such:

```
class GenericNumber<NumType> {
  zeroValue: NumType;
  add: (x: NumType, y: NumType) => NumType;
}

let myGenericNumber = new GenericNumber<number>();
myGenericNumber.zeroValue = 0;
myGenericNumber.add = function (x, y) {
  return x + y;
};
```

But when I try to implement my own Generic class like so:

```
class GenClass<Gen> {
  func: <Gen>(a: Gen) => Gen;
}

let f = new GenClass<string>();
f.func = function(a: string) { 
  return a.repeat(5);
}
```

I get an error:

```
generics.ts:30:11 - error TS2339: Property 'repeat' does not exist on type 'Gen'.

30  return a.repeat(5);
             ~~~~~~
```

If I try annotating the `a` parameter:

```
let f = new GenClass<string>();
f.func = function(a: string) {
  return a.repeat(5);
}
```

I get a different error:

```
generics.ts:29:1 - error TS2322: Type '<Gen>(a: string) => any' is not assignable to type '<Gen>(a: Gen) => Gen'.
  Types of parameters 'a' and 'a' are incompatible.
    Type 'Gen' is not assignable to type 'string'.

29 f.func = function(a: string) {
   ~~~~~~
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `func: <Gen>(a: Gen) => Gen` is defining a method with a _new_ generic type named `Gen`, **not** using the one from the class definition.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That is my problem after all. Removing the type declaration for `Gen` in `func` fixes everything. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out my problem was that in the definition of `func`, I was declaring a new type parameter, instead of reusing the one defined for the class.
Should have done:

```
class GenClass<Gen> {
  func: (a: Gen) => Gen;
}
```

instead of:

```
class GenClass<Gen> {
  func: <Gen>(a: Gen) => Gen;
}
```

Thanks to @jonrsharpe for his comment!